# C++ set different value with pragma pack runs under the same time

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

I want to test the performance of a cpp program with different memory alignment. I write down "#pragma pack(1)" and "#pragma pack(8)" in two individual test. I record the running time of both programs to compare the difference.
In my imagine, the pack(1) must be slower. However the result is the same. I don't understand why.
Here is my test code:

```
#pragma pack(8)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utility>
#include <time.h>

struct A
{
    char c;
    double d;
    int n;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    time_t stime, etime;
    stime = time(NULL);

    A a[10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        int index = i % 10000;
        a[index].d = 10.1;
    }
    printf("sizeof A: %d\n", sizeof(A));

    etime = time(NULL);
    printf("total time: %f\n", difftime(etime, stime));
    return 0;
}
```

result with pack(1):

```
sizeof A: 13
total time: 5.000000
```

result with pack(8):

```
sizeof A: 24
total time: 5.000000
```

Comment: Broken benchmark, you are not measuring what you think you are.  On a demand-page virtual memory operating system like Linux, macOS, Windows, etc, you actually measure how quickly the OS can handle page-faults and allocate RAM.  Initialize the array first before you start measuring.

Comment: I have replaced A a[10000] with A a. And removed int index = 1 % 10000. replaced a[index].d = 10.1 with a.d = i. The execution time becomes 3s. But still the same with pack(1) and pack(8) @Hans Passant

Comment: Misalignment across an L1 cache line is costly, you are no longer measuring that.  You need a better timer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Maybe I need to find a timer outside the program. @HansPassant